# Count and sum Intersects of an IEnumerable List of 2-tuple lists of objects in c#

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I want to Count and sum Intersects of an IEnumerable List of 2-tuple lists of objects. For example
how do i use the Intersect to get a sum of all the intersecting 2-tuples.

```
var combinations = ls.Select(x => ls.Where(y => ls.IndexOf(y) > ls.IndexOf(x))
                                                          .Select(z => new List<Foo> { x, z }))
                                                          .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: Could you please post an exemple of list values and the expect result?

Comment: Instead of repeatedly using IndexOf, which is going to be very slow, try using the overload of Select/Where that passes the index into your lambda expression: `ls.Select((item, index) => ...)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't completely understand what you are asking - your sample doesn't make it clear.

If it helps, there is an Intersect method in Linq: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but does this help?

```
 List<int> X = new List<int>();
 List<int> Y = new List<int>();

 int countOfIntersections = X.Intersect(Y).Count();
 int sumOfIntersections = X.Intersect(Y).Sum();
```

**EDIT**

Wait, are you looking for the Cartesian product of two lists?

```
 List<int> XList = new List<int>();
 List<int> YList = new List<int>();

 var tuples = from x in XList
              from y in YList
              select new { x, y };
```

Comment: I have a list of objects A with each object of A containing list of strings B. I use A to create a new list C that contains combinations taking 2 at a time of list A. Using list C i want to use the Intersect keyword to find and sum all the Intersecting values of B that is contained in each element of C

Comment: Please post a more complete code sample, the code you have currently, and what values you're expecting to get